# Disable IPv6 from boot inside LXD/LXC container

Tags: 16.04, lxc, ipv6, lxd

I'm using an `ubuntu:xenial` spawned container in LXD/LXC and can't work out why it keeps booting with an IPv6 link local address (`fe80::`). If it's at all relevant, I'm also using Xenial as the container host.

There are no IPv6 entries in `/etc/hosts`. There are no IPv6 addresses defined in any of `/etc/network/interfaces*`.

I've added `net.ipv6.conf.*.disable_ipv6=1` to `/etc/sysctl.conf` and although this works to clear the assigned link local addresses when you run `sysctl -p` *after* boot, it doesn't seem to run *during* boot so the container starts with the IPv6 link local addresses assigned.

I've added `ipv6.disable=1 ipv6.disable_ipv6=1` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` inside the container in `/etc/default/grub.d/50-cloudimg-settings.cfg` but that seems to do nothing. This makes sense as there's no `update-grub2` inside these containers so presumably Grub plays no part in the container startup process. I haven't managed to work out how the container decides what to try and enable or disable inside it's view of the kernel, otherwise I would try putting a setting there.

It seems I'm missing some fundamental understanding of what's causing these link local addresses to get assigned during container boot.

Any ideas or suggestions?

<sub>Please don't waste time preaching how I should learn to love IPv6. My employer is not going to use IPv6 for a long time as there is so much legacy network connected equipment that is extremely expensive and will never work on IPv6 that you would be wasting your typing.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

*An* answer (or kludge), but not what I consider *the* answer is to add `/sbin/sysctl -p` to `/etc/rc.local`.

I hope there's a more elegant solution.